# what does "well-served" mean in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was reading an article of TE，there is a sentence that I can't quite understand.

> The party does not publicly justify these moves in the name of common prosperity, but there are plenty of online commentators in China who see the pursuit of that nebulous goal as well-served by anything that creates pain for the super-rich.

"see the pursuit of that nebulous goal as well-served by anything ", Would someone tell me what does this sentence mean?

Comment: Anything which creates problems for super-rich people is seen as being good for 'common prosperity', though it  is a 'nebulous' goal (it isn't very clear exactly what it means).

Comment: [Would somebody tell me what that sentence means?]

Answer (score 2):

"that nebulous goal" refers to "common prosperity", so the sense of the passage is:

"The party doesn't state that the changes will help achieve common prosperity, but many people think it must help, since it targets the super-rich."

Answer (score 0):

serve well:
Definitions of serve well
verb promote, benefit, or be useful or beneficial to
synonyms:serve

[definition of serve well](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/serve%20well)

1. X can serve a goal: be useful or beneficial to it.
2. passive usage: well served

The passive usage is very common in English:

- The goals of the organization **were well served** by the decision of its board of directors.
- Boards of directors are **well served** by setting clear goals.

A nebulous [fuzzy, unclear] goal is well served by anything [politically, socially, economically, for example] by |anything that creates pain for the super rich|.

In this case, an **unclear** goal is well served by what creates pain for the super rich.

The goal here refers to the goal the party is pursuing.